# Reinitialize get-only properties when copying record struct using 'with' keyword

Tags: c#, initialization, record, with-statement

I have a record with a get-only property derived from one of the constructor parameters:

```cs
public readonly record struct FooRecord(string Foo)
{
    public IList<string> SomeDerivedProperty { get; } = Foo.Split('.').ToList();
}
```

If I make a copy of the record using the `with` keyword, the get-only property isn't re-initialized on the new record.

```cs
FooRecord record1 = new("Hello.World");
FooRecord record2 = record1 with { Foo = "A.B.C" };
Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(".", record2.SomeDerivedProperty)); // Outputs "Hello.World" instead of "A.B.C"
```

Is there a way to make the get-only property be re-initialized on the new record, after it's been assigned the new constructor parameter value?

Comment: I assume you want to still be able to change the list in some way after a `FooRecord` is instantiated? i.e. having the getter directly return the list, `public IList<string> SomeDerivedProperty => Foo.Split('.').ToList();` is not an option?

Comment: I will never need to set the derived properties after the record is instantiated. The list was just an example; Some of my properties have computationally expensive initialization logic that I only want to compute once when the record is created, instead of every time the property is accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`record1 with { Foo = "A.B.C" }` does two things - copies `record1`, and calls the `init`er of `Foo`. You cannot control how a record *struct* is copied, according to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression#custom-copy-semantics). So we are left with the `init`er of `Foo`, in which we can insert the logic of "set `SomeDerivedProperty` according to the new value".

```
public readonly record struct FooRecord(string foo)
{
    // assign the primary constructor parameter to a field instead
    private readonly string foo = foo;
    
    // write the getter and initer of the Foo property explicitly
    public string Foo {
        get => foo;
        init {
            foo = value;
            SomeDerivedProperty = foo.Split('.').ToList();
        }
    }
    
    // unfortunately there is a little bit of code duplication here
    public readonly IList<string> SomeDerivedProperty = foo.Split('.').ToList();
}
```